# chebshev series expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to use the Chebshev series to expansed this function

$$f(x)=\frac{4}{5-3x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n T_n(x)$$

$$a_n=\frac{\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{f(x)T_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx}{\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{T_n^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx}=\frac{\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{(\frac{4}{5-3x})T_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx}{\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{T_n^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx}$$

how can I get the above part..?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to go through integration ?

Answer (score 0):

For a **truncated** expansion, a very lazy solution could consist in the development of the lhs as a Taylor series (built at $x=0$) and to replace each $x^n$ by the corresponding linear expansion in terms of Chebyshav polynomials. Looking at page 5 of the document found http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap6.pdf

you will find these relations up to $x^{11}$.